# Are these glmer and mblogit models equivalent?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multinomial-logit

I'm trying to eventually fit a multinomial mixed effects model. It seems `mclogit::mblogit` can do this, so I'm trying to compare it with `lme4::glmer` on a binomial model first.

Are these two models based on sample data the same?

```
library(lme4)
library(HSAUR3) # toenail data
library(mclogit)
gl <- glmer(outcome~visit+(1|treatment), data=toenail, family=binomial)
mb = mblogit(outcome~visit, random=~1|treatment, data=toenail)
```

I get differences in the outputs, but I don't know if that's just different optimisers stopping in essentially the same flat space, or a fundamental difference in the model specification.

If I can first establish that `mb` and `gl` are the same model spec then there will be further questions (and I've also started a discussion in the package github but its very quiet over there...)